# Express.js module defined within the router problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, node-modules

I'm writing a project with Express.js, but I'm stuck at a certain point. Speaking about the problem, the 'slug' variable I defined in app.js is not being recognized in the controllers I wrote within the router. Is it possible to define these variables in a suitable place since I will be using them frequently?

Example;

```
MyRoute.js
        
const express=require('express')
        var slug_convert = require('slug')
        ....
        const  TestController  = require('../controllers/Platform_Controllers/Specialty')
        ....
        router.post('/specialty/:action',middleware,TestController);
```

I don't want to add the 'slug' module to each page where the controllers are located because I'm concerned about the potential performance impact on the client side due to frequent usage

```
    Controller.js
    const TestController = async (req, res) => {
    
   if(!req.params.action){

        return res.status(200).json({ "status":"no", "message":"The operation could not be selected."});
    }

    var action = req.params.action;

    if(action == "create"){
    ......
        var _MainSlug = await slug_convert(_GroupText, { locale: _GroupTextLang });
    
     };
    
    module.exports = TestController;
```

Error;

```
ReferenceError: slug_convert is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the `slug_convert` function as a variable.

```js
// slug.js (for example)
const slug_convert = async () => {
  //whatever your function is doing
}
const TestController = new TestController(slug_convert)


// controller.js
export class TestController {
  constructor(slug_convert) {
    this.slug_convert;
  }

  //add some routes
  myRoute = async (req, res) => {
    await this.slug_convert();
  }
}
```

This is also great for testing as you can mock the `slug_convert` function now.

Comment: slug is modules bro not .js or ts script.

Comment: This does not change my answer. The above code was just a demonstration. It shouldn't matter wheter its a module, function, class or if you're using js compared to ts.